# Firebase Authentication - Log in with existing WP website credentials?

Tags: android, wordpress, firebase-authentication

As the title suggests, is this doable?

From some research I'm only finding information on how to login/register into a WP installation with Firebase credentials, I'd like for the opposite. A user already exists on a WP site, and via my Android app I'd like to use those credentials to validate via Firebase Auth, but can't seem to find any reading material on the subject? I could be thinking about this wrong but seems like a valid use of Auth?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to create a [custom auth provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth).  You will need to add a backend endpoint that allows you to [create a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) using the Firebase Admin SDK, given your existing token provided by WP (or whatever it is that validates the user account in WP).  Once your client app receives this custom token, you can use it to sign in to Firebase just like any other account.